# Nesting Switch components with global NoMatch component in react-router-v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My app is currently separated into 3 parts:

- Frontend
- Administration
- Error

Frontend, Administration and the Error component have their own styling.

The Frontend and Administration component are also have their own Switch component to navigate through them.

The problem I am facing is that I can't hit the NoMatch path without a Redirect component. But when I do this I lose the wrong path in the browser URL.

Is there a chance when the inner Switch component has no matching route that it keeps searching in its parent Switch component?

Then I would be able to hit the NoMatch route and also keep the wrong path in the URL.

**Edit: I updated my answer below with the final solution that is working like intended.**

```
const Frontend = (props) => {
  const { match } = props;
  return (<div>
    <h1>Frontend</h1>
    <p><Link to={match.path}>Home</Link></p>
    <p><Link to={`${match.path}users`}>Users</Link></p>
    <p><Link to="/admin">Admin</Link></p>
    <p><Link to={`${match.path}not-found-page`}>404</Link></p>
    <hr />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={match.path} component={Home} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}users`} component={Users} />
      {
      // Workaround
      }
      <Redirect to="/error" />
    </Switch>
  </div>);
};

const Admin = (props) => {
  const { match } = props;
  return (<div>
    <h1>Admin</h1>
    <p><Link to={match.path}>Dashboard</Link></p>
    <p><Link to={`${match.path}/users`}>Edit Users</Link></p>
    <p><Link to="/">Frontend</Link></p>
    <p><Link to={`${match.path}/not-found-page`}>404</Link></p>
    <hr />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={match.path} component={Home} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/users`} component={Users} />
      {
      // Workaround
      }
      <Redirect to="/error" />
    </Switch>
  </div>);
};

const ErrorPage = () =>
  <div>
    <h1>404 not found</h1>
    <p><Link to="/">Home</Link></p>
  </div>;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AddressBar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/error" component={ErrorPage} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route path="/" component={Frontend} />
      {
      // this should render the error page
      // instead of redirecting to /error
      }
      <Route component={ErrorPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: How are you bringing in app, admin, etc?

Comment: App is the main react component if that is what you mean.

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you should add `exact` to the index path in App.js, `<Route exact path="/" component={Frontend} />`. The problem is that it's catching all requests, thus your error route is never rendered.

Comment: That was my first solution. But when you add `exact ` to the first `Route` the inner `Route`'s aren't reachable anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the final solution for this kind of requirement.
To make it work we use the location's state property. On the redirect in the inner routes we set the state to `error: true`.
On the GlobalErrorSwitch we check the state and render the error component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <div><h1>Home</h1></div>;
const User = () => <div><h1>User</h1></div>;
const Error = () => <div><h1>Error</h1></div>

const Frontend = props => {
  console.log('Frontend');
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Frontend</h2>
      <p><Link to="/">Root</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/user">User</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/admin">Backend</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/the-route-is-swiggity-swoute">Swiggity swooty</Link></p>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/user' component={User}/>
        <Redirect to={{
          state: { error: true }
        }} />
      </Switch>
      <footer>Bottom</footer>
    </div>
  );
}

const Backend = props => {
  console.log('Backend');
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Backend</h2>
      <p><Link to="/admin">Root</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/admin/user">User</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/">Frontend</Link></p>
      <p><Link to="/admin/the-route-is-swiggity-swoute">Swiggity swooty</Link></p>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/admin' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/admin/user' component={User}/>
        <Redirect to={{
          state: { error: true }
        }} />
      </Switch>
      <footer>Bottom</footer>
    </div>
  );
}

class GlobalErrorSwitch extends Component {
  previousLocation = this.props.location

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    const { location } = this.props;

    if (nextProps.history.action !== 'POP'
      && (!location.state || !location.state.error)) {
        this.previousLocation = this.props.location
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const isError = !!(
      location.state &&
      location.state.error &&
      this.previousLocation !== location // not initial render
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {          
          isError
          ? <Route component={Error} />
          : <Switch location={isError ? this.previousLocation : location}>
              <Route path="/admin" component={Backend} />
              <Route path="/" component={Frontend} />
            </Switch>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Route component={GlobalErrorSwitch} />
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I think you don't need the `previousLocation` logic.

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works well. ("react": "^16.7.0", "react-router": "^4.3.1")

Comment: Nice to hear. 

Answer (score 0):

All child component routes are wrapped in the `<Switch>` the parent (the `switch` inside the `app` component) you don't actually the switch in the child components.

Simply remove child switch.component and let the 404 in the `<App` `<Switch>` catch any missing.

Comment: When I remove the <Switch> component inside App it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you post a codepen to show an example of what isn't working?

Comment: Looking at your update, it appears you have removed the switch as per my answer (which is working for you). Your new question, about a leading slash not working is a new and unrelated question...

Comment: Not really because the / was part of my question at first. Thanks tho.